# How to display data from tables and queries for each line of data from another table in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tables - animals and animals_type.

Columns in animals_type: **id** and **type**

Columns in animals: **id**, **name** and **animals_type**

I want to render list of animals type and exists animals on same page.

For render animals type I create model Animals_type, controller Animals_TypeController

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Animals_type;

class Animals_typeController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Animals_type::find();

        $pagination = new Pagination([
            'defaultPageSize' => 10,
            'totalCount' => $query->count(),
        ]);

        $Animals_type = $query->orderBy('id')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'animals_type' => $Animals_type,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and view index.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

?>
    <h1>Animals Type</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($animals_types as $animals_type):?>
            <li>
                <?= Html::encode("{$animals_type->type} ({$animals_type->id})") ?>:
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

How right to query list of animals for each type?

Comment: create a relation in your Animals_type model that will give you all Animal models with this animal_type.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data

Comment: AxelPAL, ok. And how better use these results in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creatring the relation **animals** you can use it somehow like this:

```
<?php foreach ($animals_types as $animals_type):?>
    <li>
        <?= Html::encode("{$animals_type->type} ({$animals_type->id})") ?>:
    <?if($animals_type->animals):?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($animals_type->animals as $animal):?>
                <?= Html::encode("{$animal->name} ({$animal->id})") ?>:
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?endif?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```